# override default css for HTML label

Tags: html, css

```
 <label id="test" class="hidden" ><strong>Label Text</strong></label> 

 .hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

The above code is working as expected

But when i add new class col_1 am having issue

```
<label id="test" class="hidden col_1" ><strong>Label Text</strong></label> 

  .hidden
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

in firebug i see that below css on label which is causing that issue  which is using **kickstart css**. So i don want to touch the below code

```
label[class*="col_"]{
display:inline-block;
}
```

What is the best way to override the default label behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: display:inline-block !important;

Comment: `display: none !important` because the op wants the same behavior as before adding the class `col_n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
label[class*="col_"].hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

Or this:

```
label[class*="col_"]:not(.hidden){
   display:inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqnvU/

Comment: This is coming from Kickstart...Any other alternative. i ll update my question

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
#test.col_1{display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the code:

```
label[class*="col_"]{
display:inline-block;
}
```

It seemed from your question that you weren't aware of that code.

Easiest solution is

```
label.hidden
{
    display:none !important;
}
```